# How to copy down a formula that uses arrays?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 25000 rows of data and within them, I have 50 unique variables. Therefore, these variables are expressed 500 times (or "scenarios")

My formula:

`=IF(K2>$K$3,3,IF(K2=0,0,IF(L1=3,2,IF(COUNT($L1:L$2)>(64-$L$2-COUNTIF($K$3:$K$51,">0")),1,2))))`

My formula assigns either a `3`, `2`, or `1` to each of the 50 variables depending on the scenario, however, it only works for one scenario.

I obviously cannot fill down this formula for all 500 scenarios. However, I need a quick way to apply  this formula for all scenarios.

Is there a way to quickly do this or do I need to come up with a better formula?

Comment: So you're asking how to copy a formula to other cells?  I think this question id probably better suited to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), as it is not a programming question. Also, check out the see the [help/on-topic], and here are some good tips from [so]'s top user:  [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: I'm not following what is limiting this from being copied down

Comment: @Brad, This formula works for one scenario with the 50 variables. The reason why it would not copy down is because the $ signs make some of the variables constants within the formula. $K$3 will always be cell K3 for all 500 scenarios. However, when I go to the second scenario, I would need this to be K53 and in the third scenario, I would need it to be K103.

Comment: What determines which "scenario" you are using? Are the scenarios side by side? Underneath each other? There are ways to make a cell reference skip rows/columns when copied across and/or down, but in order to give you a formula you would need to share your data structure.

Comment: Vba would be able to apply the formula to fifty rows, then to update the reference cell, then apply that to the next fifty rows and so-on. I would suggest writing the code in a loop and it would likely run in less than 5 seconds.

Comment: If you reorder your table would these formulas be broken? Can you separate whatever data is in `$K$3` type cells into another table and use a `vlookup` to establish the value? That way you can use the same formula for all cells and order is no longer important. But I think you'd need to post come sample data for us to come up with a meaningful solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a formula that changes the cell reference from K3 to K53 and so on, every 50 rows. Also, the reference to K3:K51 will adjust to K53:K101 etc.

Using Index instead of Indirect, this formula is not volatile and should not cause slowness.

```
=IF(K2>INDEX(K:K,(CEILING(ROW(A1)/50,1)*50)-50+3),3,IF(K2=0,0,IF(L1=3,2,IF(COUNT($L1:L$2)>(64-$L$2-COUNTIF(INDEX(K:K,(CEILING(ROW(A1)/50,1)*50)-50+3):INDEX(K:K,(CEILING(ROW(A1)/50,1)*50)-50+51),">0")),1,2))))
```

Comment: Hey Teylyn, This is almost what I need. I would have never known how to do it this way. I fixed your formula slightly but there is one more thing I need. For a portion of the formula, I need to change IF(COUNT($L$1:L1) so when I get to the second scenario, it reads IF(COUNT($L$51:L51) and so forth.

Comment: Actually, I figured out my question to your answer. Thanks so much. You are a life saver!